# Simple login with PWA React Application

Tags: reactjs, progressive-web-apps

I'm new in PWA and want to create PWA and React to create Android and iOS apps. I only have the REST APIs (including login with username and password). I would like to create an app with login and display my pages in the menu on the left side.
Could you suggest a Doc or GitLab source where I can start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your normal React project complete with the features and functionality you intend to have then convert into a PWA after that.

To add PWA functionality into a plain React project, you can follow the steps outlined [here](https://dev.to/icyybee/the-ultimate-guide-to-converting-react-apps-to-progressive-web-apps-1pnp)

To add PWA functionality to a Next JS project, I would recommend making use of  [this package](https://github.com/shadowwalker/next-pwa). [Here](https://dev.to/anuraggharat/pwa-with-nextjs-5178) is an article that walks you through how to achieve that.

You can publish your PWAs to Play store and App store, read more [here](https://www.pwabuilder.com/)